# Structure a table with many columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, enums

On a SQL Server database I have a table with about 200 items:

```
create table dbo.Reports
(
  Id int identity not null,
  HealthRating int not null, --- { One of: NoProblems; TemporaryChange; ... }
  Hobbies int not null, --- { Many of: None, Running, Tennis, Football, Swimming }
  HobbiesOthers nvarchar (400) null
  -- More 100 columns
);
```

So I have about 200 columns with types: INT, NVARCHAR, BIT and DATETIME.

Some of the INT columns are as HealthRating to store one value.

Others are like Hobbies to hold many items ... And usually have an extra column to store other options as text (nvarchar) ...

How should I structure this table? I see 3 options:

1. Have one column for each property so:

   HealthRatingNoProblems bit no null, 
    HealthRatingTemporaryChange bit no null,
2. Create lookup tables for HealthRatings, Hobbies, ...
   Probably I will end with more 60 tables or so ...
3. Use Enums and Flag enums which are now supported in Entity Framework and store one choice and multiple choice items in Int columns as I posted.

What would you suggest?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. In particular, are there any of the `null` columns that need to be set when other columns are set in particular ways?

Comment: You mean if HobbiesOthers is conditioned by what is set in Hobbies? Well, in theory if Hobbies is None then HobbiesOthers should be null ... But this seems hard to do so I am considering that when Hobbies is None it means that no item was selected. So in my application to check if no Hobbies exist I just check if Hobbies is None and if HobbiesOthers is null. Is this what you asked?

Comment: Yes, but one would need the answer for all the columns.

Comment: If users can define their own hobbies then I would get rid of the Hobbies and HobbiesOthers columns. Instead, I would have a master hobbies tables and each hobby would have a HobbyId and a HobbyName. Then there would be a lookup table to map hobbies to Ids.

As for HealthRating, some programmers choose to create a lookup table and some choose to store the value as the enum int value, and some choose to store it as the enum name.  My preference for Enums is to store the name.

I would not use an Enum for fields that can be defined by the user.

Answer (score 0):

By all means -- please! -- normalize that poor table. If you end up with 50 or 60 tables then so be it. That is the design. If a user has a hobby, that information will be in the Hobby table. If he has three hobbies, there will be three entries in the Hobby table. If he doesn't have any hobbies, there will be nothing in the Hobby table. So on with all the other tables.

And for all those times you are only interested in hobbies, you only involve the Hobby table with the Reports table and leave all the other tables alone. You can't do that with one huge, all encompassing row that attempts to hold everything. There, if you only want to look at hobby information, you still have to read in the entire row, bringing in all that data you don't want. Why read in data you are just going to discard?